# Align left-aligned formula at two points

Tags: align

I would like to get this WITHOUT using tables, because in my real equations there are fractions included that are scaled down in tables

```
a+b+c=1
y    =2
```

My code looks as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
&a+b+c&=1\\
&y    &=2
\end{align*}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried thousands of things such as `flalign` and so on. But nothing works. I am really frustrated. Any ideas?

Comment: @HagenBrenner - I get the equations aligned as you wanted (at `=` and start of line) using your code and `pdflatex`.

Comment: This is because your setting are set up so that all your equations are aligned left (start of line). My equations are all centered. But I want this particular one to be left aligned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "big fractions" also inside `array`; using the `array` package helps, so say

```
\usepackage{array}
```

in your preamble. Then you can use

```
\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}>{\displaystyle{}}l@{}}
a+b+c &= y           \\
y     &= \frac{2}{3}
\end{array}
```

just as a single (math) object that you can put anywhere you like. Adding `\vphantom{\frac{2}{3}}` before the `\\` in the first row can help spacing.

[image]

For example, with

```
\begin{flalign*}
\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}>{\displaystyle{}}l@{}}
    a+b+c &= y           \vphantom{\frac{2}{3}}\\
    y     &= \frac{2}{3}
\end{array}
&&
\end{flalign*}
```

you'll get the object flush with the left margin.

Comment: Hi egreg, this solutions is brilliant! thank you so much! there is just one thing that disturbs me. the space between the lines of the array is to small. I put in brackts the space in cm behind \\. Is there a more generic way to do this?

Comment: @HagenBrenner You might set `\arraystretch` to a different value: for example `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` just after `\begin{flalign*}` or, in any case, before the `array` environment.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\phantom` to apply the appropriate spacing within the `align` environment to ensure that the `y` is aligned with the `a` and the `=` signs are also aligned. If you want this entire equation adjacent to the left margin you can use `flalign`.

[image]

### Note:

- Note the trailing `&` which is needed to get equation all the way to the left margin.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% Uncomment to see margins

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
                 a+b+c&=1 &\\% Need this trailing alignment char to get all the way left
    y\phantom{{}+b+c} &=2 &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But this answere does not left-align the formulas.

My formulas are all centered. Again, my question is: How can write formulas like this but in addition to that left align them?

I want the left alignment only for this single formula, not for all formulas.

Comment: @HagenBrenner: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Have updated solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your answer

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}‎
&a+b+c&&=1\\‎‎
&y&&=2
\end{alignat*}
```

Explanation: `align` is an environment for shifting between left-aligned columns and right-aligned ones, so if you want your equation to be shown as a totally left-aligned one, you need to add an extra column between the left-aligned columns. In the above example, first `&` in each line makes a left-aligned column, if you delete this ones you'll get a right-aligned column. The second ampersands in each line make a right-aligned column but we don't need this column so we add a third column by adding an `&` after the last ampersands in each line. `flalign` is a variation of `align` that increases the space between columns so as to cover the line completely. `alignat` omits unnecessary spaces between the columns (the other difference between `alignat` and `align` is that the first one takes an argument which shows the number of the columns). Note that adding a `*` after each of these three, makes them untaged.

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't higher up, as it seems like it solves OP's problem exactly. Is there a reason to avoid alignat* ?

Comment: Excellent solution, far simpler. [User's Guide for ams math Package](http://www.utexas.edu/ogs/etd/LaTeX/Mathematics+AMS/amsmdoc.pdf) presents both `alignat` and `flalign` as standard alignment environments for displayed equations.

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for. This should be the accepted answer. I didn't know that align shifts between left and right alignment, nor why code snippets I found around the web used && instead of &. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use big fractions inline, use `\dfrac{}{}` instead of `\frac{}{}`.
`flalign` needs an extra ampersand at the end to really align left.
Here is a not-really-minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt e magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
%
In order for \verb+flalign+ to align left, 
you need to put an ampersand at the end of the line.
I cannot really explain why, but it works.
\begin{flalign}
a   &=3         & \\
b   &=4         & \\
c   &=a+b       & 
\end{flalign}
%
To have several equation columns side-by-side, 
use extra ampersands to separate the columns:
\begin{flalign}
x       &=y         & X         &=Y         &\\
x'      &=y'        & X'        &=Y'        &\\
x+x'    &=y+y'      & X+X'      &=Y+Y'      &
\end{flalign}
%
Line-by-line annotations on an equation can be done by judicious application of
\verb+\text{}+ inside an align environment.
Out of the two \verb+&&+ the first one creates a new column 
and the second one is for alingment.
\begin{flalign}
 x& = y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dots     && \text{by Axiom 1.}   &\\
  & = y’\circ y^*                   && \text{by Axiom 2.}   &\\
  & = y(0) y’                       && \text {by Axiom 3.}  &
\end{flalign}
%
To have big fractions inline in text or tables/tabulars, 
use \verb+\dfrac{}{}+ instead of \verb+\frac{}{}+. 
It will result in a big fraction like $\dfrac{3}{4}$ instead of $\frac{3}{4}$.
\end{document}
```